# Every time I reconnect to a MySQL database, all the tables are empty

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, datagrip

I'm very new to MySQL, so I started by using www.freesqldatabase.com to set up a database. Whenever I connect to it, I can set up tables and databases that will persist over connections, but any data I input is unique to that connection. Even if I'm viewing the database via DataGrip, if I add a row to a table I can't view it when I refresh datagrip, but my Python program can retrieve the data it just created from the database. When I retrieve a new connection to the database, however, none of the rows in the tables exist.

For example, on my auth table (which has two keys: "id" and "token"), I would do:

```
insert into auth values ('id', 'token')
select id from auth where token = 'token'
```

And as a result I would get 'id'. But when I start a new connection to the database and do

```
select id from auth where token = 'token'
```

It get back that none exist. I do that same request in DataGrip, same username/password/ip/database, and I get the same error.

I've also tried doing this on Google Cloud SQL service, but I get the same exact issues. So it's not an issue with the server I'm using.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Seems like you are not commiting the transaction. What do you get from `select @@autocommit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set autocommit to true when I connected to my database, and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute

```
insert into auth values ('id', 'token');
commit;
```